# Looping through Google Sheet

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a hard time with Ranges and figuring out why I need to add **i+1** in **getRange** to get the correct cell in my loop.  I'm not sure if its because I increment before the variable or if it has something to do with the initial value?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();`

for (var i = 3; i < 30; ++i) {
  var row = values[i];
  var msgSent = row[3];
  sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue("ALERTED");
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.getRange()` just uses integer based referencing while the 2D array of `values` needs to be referenced with a zero-based approach.

The 1st row (array) in `values` is `values[0]`, but `.getRange()` uses `.getRange(1, 1)` to reference the 1st row, 1st column of the sheet. The 1st column value in the 1st row would be `values[0][0]`.

Now if you're looping through 30 or so rows and want to set the values all at once, which is much better than setting them one-by-one, it'll look some thing like this...

```js
var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var newValues = [];
for (var i = 3; i < 30; ++i) {
  var row = values[i];
  var msgSent = row[3];
  newValues.push(["ALERTED"]);
}
s.getRange(4, 4).offset(0, 0, newValues.length).setValues(newValues);
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  Is there a way to use the zero approach for a `.get`?  This is part of my larger script that shows if an email has been sent so I have to loop individually.